# Disable extension from a specific site

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[image: disable extension to site]

If you see screenshot above, it has only an option to `allow this extension on specific sites`. Is there any option to disallow to specific sites?

Comment: There's no such feature in general so you'll have to add an explicit check in your scripts. For content scripts however you can specify [exclude_matches](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#matchAndGlob).

Comment: tldr; could you please tell me from where do I start that?